# Which direction will this object move in at the end of this process?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

1. Consider an object with no net force acting on it moving with a constant velocity $v$.
   It has a momentum $mv$.
2. Now let a force $F_1$ act on the object. Let the direction of this force be opposite (to the direction of the object's constant velocity)
3. The object now undergoes a change in its momentum over time,  accelerating in the direction of the force $F_1$
4. Let another force $F_2$ be introduced that is equal in magnitude to $F_1$ but opposite in direction.

**Question:** What happens to the object now?

Since under the influenced of  balanced forces the object can either be at rest or have a constant velocity. If it does have a constant velocity what will be its direction?

And what is the work done by the two forces?

[image]

Comment: As $F_1$ is applied the object's velocity component in its original direction of motion will decrease. That should be fairly obvious. Suggest you start by writing an equation for this velocity component, showing how it depends on time $t$ from when $F_1$ started to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

The object will stop to accelerate since the two forces cancel each other. The final velocity v will be 
$v=v_0+a*t_0$
where $v_0$ is the initial velocity, a the acceleration provided by $F_1$ and $t_0$ the time until $F_2$ is applied. Note that $v_0$ and $a$ most likely have different direction.

Answer (score 0):

Before the second force is added ,the first force imparts a change of momentum F*t where t is the duration of the force, so the total momentum will be m*v + f*t. and the total work done by this force during this time will be 1/2mv^2 - 1/2m*(v+f*t/m)^2  when the second force is added it will continue to move at a velocity v+f*t/m with zero acceleration. meaning zero work is now being done by the forces